# What reasonable context could there be for this sentence: *I have raised my kids well*?

Tags: meaning

A tutorial gives this example:

> I have raised my kids well.

What might be a reasonable context for this sentence? Have the kids have grown up?

Comment: Yes. Pragmatically, the kids *must* have grown up, because Present Perfect ***have raised*** (as opposed to ***am raising*** or ***have been raising***) implies a ***completed*** action. That's to say, since the kids ***are*** "raised", their "raising" was done in the past, so by now they're no longer being raised - they're grown up.

Comment: (Okay - I accept that *in a specific context*, it's possible that children who are *still* being "raised" have just done something that shows how well brought up they are *already*. Which their mother might boast about using a Past Tense reference even though the process is actually still "ongoing".)